# Codeigniter - Unset session in a Two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I created `two-dimensional array` of session. Where a user can input an item and when he/she clicks the `ADD button` an `array` of that item will inserted in a session called `item_names`. Now I'm trying and cannot `unset` a certain item whenever a user clicks `delete button` which has it's `unique id` on it. I've found out that the function `unset_userdata()` don't support associative array already, as what I'm trying to achieve. Is there any functions aside from this?

Controller.php

```
public function delete_item(){
    $app_no = $this->input->post('app_no');  // product id of item
    $items_session = $this->session->userdata('item_names');

     foreach ($items_session as $key => $value) {
        if($value['product_id'] == $app_no){
            $this->session->unset_userdata($items_session[$key][$app_no]); 
        }
    }
  }
```

Array structure

```
Array
   (
       [0] => Array
     (
         [product_id] => 201708010010
         [product_name] => LADDER BRICK
         [total_prod_price] => P50
         [requestQty] => 1
     )
   (
```

Comment: show your array structure

Comment: @Irfan updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly unset specific value of multidimensional array in session of codeingiter. You have to take all session value to variable. Unset the specific value and again set the variable in session as shown below:

```
    $items_session = $this->session->userdata('item_names');
    unset($items_session[$key][$app_no]);
    $this->session->set_userdata('item_names',$items_session);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks didn't figured it out, I've already done this in my add button function!

Comment: Is it better/faster to just manipulate the $_SESSION variable directly? I always do in this case to avoid having to reload session data every time. I'm not sure how big of an impact this has on memory.

Comment: Yes you can directly edit $_SESSION variable . If you check unset_userdata() function in session class of codeigniter , it also does same in foreach Loop. So you can do accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn to regular PHP with [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
public function delete_item(){
    $app_no = $this->input->post('app_no');  // product id of item
    $items_session = $this->session->userdata('item_names');

     foreach ($items_session as $key => $value) {
        if($value['product_id'] == $app_no){
            unset($items_session[$key][$app_no]); 
        }
    }
  }
```